# Edit the excerpt before it is shown

Tags: excerpt

I'm looking for a way the edit the excerpt before it get's show on the page.

The issue is this: We import data (jobs) for a third party provider and the content is divided in sections with each a header (e.g. the first one is "Introduction"). The issue now is that in the overview with the post, each excerpt looks like "Introduction. Lorem Ipsum". So I want to manipulate the data to remove "Introduction."

Are there any hooks in WordPress that I can utilize to either edit the data before shown, or is there a function that I can overwrite that display's `the_excerpt()`?

I'm using a child theme of a theme we bought and would prefer to not mess with the core files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it:

```
    function get_the_excerpt_filter( $excerpt ) {
        $wordToRemove = "Introduction";
        $len = strlen($wordToRemove);

        if(substr($excerpt, 0, $len) == $wordToRemove){
            $excerpt = trim(substr($excerpt, $len));
        }

        return $excerpt;
    }
    add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'get_the_excerpt_filter' );
```

Hope this helps someone else.